# Multiple divs problem when working with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am facing a wired problem when using Jquery Dialog.

```
  <div id="divSupplierGrid" style="display: none">
      <uc2:SupplierGrid ID="Tab1UCSupplierGrid" runat="server" />
  </div>
 <div id="divCreateInqGeneral" style="display: none">
     <uc1:CreateInqGeneral ID="Tab1UCCreateInqGeneral" runat="server" />
 </div>

function DisableBackGrd() {

        $("#divCreateInqGeneral").dialog({ bgiframe: true,
            modal: true,
            open: function () { hideScrollBars(); },
            beforeClose: function () { showScrollBars(); }
        });
    }
```

When i keep only 'divSupplierGrid' on my page .Jquery dialog works fine but as soon as i add 'divCreateInqGeneral' i get 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method' Exception. Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

what if you take the divSupplierGrid off the page?  what if you remove the server control from divCreateInqGeneral?  have you stepped through the code in the IE developer toolbar.  rest assured it's something silly.

Comment: thanks i solved it i had included Jquery js file in SupplierGrid which is older.So it was overwriting the current jquery.js